Making Finder play nice with SMB shares
Currently on Sequoia 15.2 although this is evident on earlier versions.
Summary: Finder's leftmost column which normally displays a selection of useful folders and any mounted drives also shows SMB servers present on the networks. Using them results in failure.
Detail:
Freshly booted systems.
Finder -> Go -> Connect to a Server...
Enter server address: smb://servername/sharename
Click Connect
Pop up asks to connect as a guest or registered user
Select Registered User and enter account and password
Finder opens it in the finder window with the share visible.
From here I can open files, create new folders and drag stuff into the window to copy it...
So all seems pretty normal and okay so far...
Let's navigate to another folder now - maybe my Home folder, or my Documents folder. It doesn't matter what...  That's okay too.
But... Now I want to go back to the network share.
In finder window, in the leftmost pane, under locations I can see the server is mounted and there's an eject icon next to it.
If I click on server.mydomain.com then the finder window shows an empty window with 'Connection Failed' at the top and a Connect As... button.
Clicking on the Connect As... button causes the finder window to navigate back my 'My MacBook Pro' rather than try to connect.
The only way back to the share is to navigate to /Volumes/Sharename which shows that it is mounted correctly and is accessible.
So why can't I use the shortcuts in the leftmost pane in Finder?
On my network, the servers are a Synology NAS running latest firmware and a Raspberry Pi with current Bookworm Pi OS and Samba.
Sample smb.conf from the RPi...
 [global]
   vfs objects = fruit streams_xattr
   fruit:metadata = stream
   fruit:model = MacSamba
   fruit:veto_appledouble = no
   fruit:nfs_aces = no
   fruit:wipe_intentionally_left_blank_rfork = yes
   fruit:delete_empty_adfiles = yes
   fruit:posix_rename = yes

   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   interfaces = 10.10.0.0/16
   bind interfaces only = yes

   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes

   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

   pam password change = yes

   map to guest = bad user
   netbios name = RPIServer
   usershare allow guests = yes
   min protocol = SMB2
   ea support = yes

#======================= Share Definitions =======================
[RPIShare]
  path = /mnt/volume1/nas
  valid users = user
  browsable = yes
  writable = yes
  read only = no
  comment = NAS Share
  server string = Raspberry PI Server 
  spotlight backend = elasticsearch

